# jogl native crash on call to glDisable

Tags: opengl, native, jogl

I have a jogl app that is (native) crashing on a call to glDisable (I don't think the specifics of the stack are important here - it is a call occurring on the EDT).

My question is really about how it is possible that glDisable could cause a native crash. It's always being passed a valid flag for disabling.

I have 2 thoughts on this:

1) Graphics card bug (though I have tried updating the drivers, but still it does only occur on some computers, so it's still possible it's card related).

2) The Java app is using a large amount of memory. I don't know if it's possible that if too much memory is allocated, bad things in native code can happen. Though if it's just the Java memory that's highly used, and not the overall system memory, I would think the error would show as a Java error.

Any thoughts on how this could actually happen?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time OpenGL will handle it's own errors by just ignoring the call with an error in it, but there are a few errors that will crash your application. The only ones I've ever run into are access violations and bad drivers. I have the feeling that it's not the `glDisable` call (which can only hit a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` or `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error that OpenGL itself handles with `glGetError`), but the one before that.

It would be nice to look at the code around the error, but I'm going to assume it's either during a texture load (`glTexImage2D`) or a draw call (`gl*Pointer` or `glDraw*`). If your length variables are larger than the memory that is actually for the texture/buffer, OpenGL will still attempt to read from those addresses and the OS should throw an access violation exception. Double check those variables and remember that everything uses byte length except for `glDraw*` calls, those use the number of elements.

If that's not your issue, then your `glDisable` call is the first actual OpenGL call you make and the error is that JOGL can't find opengl32.dll or libgl.so or whatever the OpenGL implementation is on your OS. In that case you just need to install the proper drivers and it'll work. Sometimes if you make a call for a method that was introduced to OpenGL in a version after what your driver supports, you'll get the same error. You can check your OpenGL version with `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`.

Comment: my thought was also that it had to do with the texture loading, but when I look at the native log produced (which is on a user's PC, so I don't have the full log here), the call it shows the violation happening on is on the call to glDisable, which is why I am stumped on this.

Comment: `glDisable` shouldn't be modifying/accessing any RAM. First I would ask the user to reinstall his graphics card drivers, and if that doesn't work, try to get a hold of the log/stack trace, look for the calls around that. If nothing else search your program for `glDisable` calls and see what OpenGL calls are being made before that. You can use tools like `glslDevil` or `gDEBugger` to help you with that.

Comment: thanks, we're doing some reinstalls of graphics card drivers and hopefully that will fix the problems...